# MySQL workbench, How to create a Filter for a Date to arrange a group

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, phpmyadmin, mysql-workbench

I am working on the date group. at the moment it doesn't return as anything result.
I have tried on different filter or group without date, and it fine and working well but I need to create a group based on date or timestamp.

Here is a code

```
SELECT 
    settlement_id,
    settlement_start_date,
    sku AS 'Settlement_sku',
        SUM(IF(transaction_type = 'order'
            AND amount_description = 'Principal'
            AND amount_type = 'ItemPrice',
        quantity_purchased,
        0)) AS 'total_QTY_Order'

FROM settlements
Where settlement_start_date ='2017-11-12'
GROUP BY sku 
HAVING Settlement_sku IS NOT NULL
    AND LENGTH(Settlement_sku) > 0
ORDER BY Settlement_sku ASC
```

as I get a result on

[image]

if I remove `where settlement_start_date ='2017-11-12'` 
and change it to `Where settlement_id ='7135956892'`

and results are working and fine, please see a screenshot

[image]

the problem is settlement_start_date is 0000-00-00 so how to get a group without depending on 0000-00-00.

Here is table
as you can see three highlights as I want Yellow highlight group with Blue highlight and ignore all red highlight

[image]

If you are not sure what I am talking about then maybe I can explain more

Comment: Not at all clear to me, If you haven't stored start-date where do you expect to get it from? It might help clarify if you added sample raw data  FROM settlements as text to your question

Comment: maybe this can help you more clear https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/h4dXWZgsHebqGyeMLSutPC/0

Answer (score 0):

You could use a self join to fill down the start and end date based on the min id for the settlement
for example

```
select #s.minid,s.maxstdate,s.maxenddate, s2.*
        id                          ,                
        s2.settlement_id        ,    
        s.maxstdate             ,    
        s.maxenddate               ,    
        deposit_date            ,    
        total_amount            ,    
        currency                ,    
        transaction_type        ,    
        order_id                ,    
        merchant_order_id       ,    
        adjustment_id           ,    
        shipment_id             ,    
        marketplace_name        ,    
        amount_type             ,    
        amount_description      ,    
        amount                  ,    
        fulfillment_id          ,    
        posted_date             ,    
        posted_date_time        ,    
        order_item_code         ,    
        merchant_order_item_id  ,    
        merchant_adjustment_item_id ,
        sku                     ,    
        quantity_purchased      ,    
        promotion_id
from
(
select s1.settlement_id , min(id) minid,max(settlement_start_date) maxstdate,max(settlement_end_date) maxenddate 
from settlements_2_test s1
group by s1.settlement_id
) s
join settlements_2_test s2 on s2.id > s.minid and s2.settlement_id = s.settlement_id
order by id,settlement_id limit 5
```

result

```
+----+---------------+------------+------------+--------------+--------------+----------+------------------+---------------------+---------------------+---------------+-------------+------------------+-------------+--------------------------+--------+----------------+-------------+-------------------------+-----------------+------------------------+-----------------------------+------------------+--------------------+--------------+
| id | settlement_id | maxstdate  | maxenddate | deposit_date | total_amount | currency | transaction_type | order_id            | merchant_order_id   | adjustment_id | shipment_id | marketplace_name | amount_type | amount_description       | amount | fulfillment_id | posted_date | posted_date_time        | order_item_code | merchant_order_item_id | merchant_adjustment_item_id | sku              | quantity_purchased | promotion_id |
+----+---------------+------------+------------+--------------+--------------+----------+------------------+---------------------+---------------------+---------------+-------------+------------------+-------------+--------------------------+--------+----------------+-------------+-------------------------+-----------------+------------------------+-----------------------------+------------------+--------------------+--------------+
|  2 |    7174103342 | 2017-12-24 | 2018-01-07 |              |         0.00 |          | Order            | 204-3505716-0081143 | 204-3505716-0081143 |               | DMX5Sr4rN   | Amazon.co.uk     | ItemPrice   | Principal                |  39.99 | AFN            | 26.12.2017  | 26.12.2017 15:08:49 UTC | 59733226356523  |                        |                             | UK-KC3816-0006   |                  1 |              |
|  3 |    7174103342 | 2017-12-24 | 2018-01-07 |              |         0.00 |          | Order            | 204-3505716-0081143 | 204-3505716-0081143 |               | DMX5Sr4rN   | Amazon.co.uk     | ItemFees    | FBAPerUnitFulfillmentFee |  -4.24 | AFN            | 26.12.2017  | 26.12.2017 15:08:49 UTC | 59733226356523  |                        |                             | UK-KC3816-0006   |                  1 |              |
|  4 |    7174103342 | 2017-12-24 | 2018-01-07 |              |         0.00 |          | Order            | 204-3505716-0081143 | 204-3505716-0081143 |               | DMX5Sr4rN   | Amazon.co.uk     | ItemFees    | Commission               |  -6.00 | AFN            | 26.12.2017  | 26.12.2017 15:08:49 UTC | 59733226356523  |                        |                             | UK-KC3816-0006   |                  1 |              |
|  5 |    7174103342 | 2017-12-24 | 2018-01-07 |              |         0.00 |          | Order            | 205-1808036-3091505 | 205-1808036-3091505 |               | D2RMyvqF4   | Amazon.co.uk     | ItemPrice   | Principal                |  29.99 | AFN            | 07.01.2018  | 07.01.2018 11:49:18 UTC | 25477500530227  |                        |                             | GB-KS8015-Grey-R |                  1 |              |
|  6 |    7174103342 | 2017-12-24 | 2018-01-07 |              |         0.00 |          | Order            | 205-1808036-3091505 | 205-1808036-3091505 |               | D2RMyvqF4   | Amazon.co.uk     | ItemFees    | FBAPerUnitFulfillmentFee |  -2.48 | AFN            | 07.01.2018  | 07.01.2018 11:49:18 UTC | 25477500530227  |                        |                             | GB-KS8015-Grey-R |                  1 |              |
+----+---------------+------------+------------+--------------+--------------+----------+------------------+---------------------+---------------------+---------------+-------------+------------------+-------------+--------------------------+--------+----------------+-------------+-------------------------+-----------------+------------------------+-----------------------------+------------------+--------------------+--------------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```